# Any command line format tool available for java file?

Tags: java, formatting

We are working on a legacy system (7 years old), with lots of java/jsp files that have never been formatted before, **not reader at all**. Because we have many old versions, we are afraid that we won't be able to effectively diff unformatted and formatted files anymore if we format them.

Are there any command line format tools available with which we can format the old version of the file before doing diff on the new?

Comment: Why not use an ide like eclipse, defining your formatting rules and reformat all the files (you may select multiple and format them with one keystroke)

Comment: How bad is the lack of formatting? Are they formatting inconsistently, are they lacking indention, or are they lacking any unnecessary whitespace at all so the code is all on one line?

Comment: Also, do you have source control? If so, which one and which version?

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while, but we used to use [Jalopy](http://jalopy.sourceforge.net/). I'm fairly certain you can run it from the command line.

Comment: I cannot find a document explaining how to run Jalopy from the command line.  Could you please show us an example?  Thanks.

Comment: IIRC, we used the console plug-in, http://jalopy.sourceforge.net/jalopy-console/index.html. This was  in a former life; I haven't used Java since then.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) will work for you.

I have also [Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) in my bookmarks, never used it.

Answer (score 1):

Both Eclipse and IntelliJ have ignore-whitespace options in their diff viewers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using eclipse source code formatter from the command line as mentioned [here](http://blogs.operationaldynamics.com/andrew/software/java-gnome/eclipse-code-format-from-command-line).

Answer (score -1):

http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/cmdline.html has commanline tool.

Comment: Does checkstyle also do formatting? My understanding is that it simply *checks* the style to make sure it's some format, it doesn't actually do any formatting itself, which means it's useless here.